# TMCbeans does not open after installation

Tags: java, netbeans, java-11

I'm currently planning to learn Java through the MOOC course but I'm unable to open the tmcbeans app after installation. I have tried reinstalling it but it does not seem to do anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue on Windows 10. I found out that TMCBeans is currently not compatible with OpenJDK Versions > 11. Thus, I did the following things for TMCBeans to function correctly.

1. Download *exactly* AdoptOpenJDK11 for your OS, open development environment for Java 11, from [the archives](https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot).
2. Try launching TMCBeans again.
3. If you're still facing issues, try following the instructions of this [Reddit post's first comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/comments/oufbxi/tmcbeans_crashes_on_startup/).

Answer (score 1):

I signed up for MOOC too, and what worked for me was to follow the steps to locate the JVM path of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_0uFioeQug)

My java ended up being under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home

I then updated and uncommented the line jdkhome= of tmcbeans.conf (as described in the comment above), saved and relaunched tmcbeans. It worked perfectly after that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in **macOs Monterey** and the following steps got  tmcbeans up and running for me:

1. Open Terminal and type `/usr/libexec/java_home-v'1.7*'` (copy/save the result)
2. Open Finder and go to `Applications -> tmcbeans.app`
3. Right click on tmcbeans.app and select `Show package contents`
4. Go to `Contents/Resources/tmcbeans/etc/` and open `tmcbeans.conf` in your preferred text editor
5. Scroll to the bottom and you will find `#jdkhome="some path here..."`
6. Copy the result from `Step 1` and paste it between the double quotes in `Step 5`
7. Remove the hash symbol at the begining to make it `jdkhome="your path here ..."`
8. `Save`, `Quit` and `Restart` tmcbeans.app

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to do the job! Is there another solution?